# Remote Validation in jQuery in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, validation, jquery-plugins

This form will INSERT  mobile number into my MYSQL db

First, I am trying to validate an mobile remotely to make sure it does not exists.

the script writes to the db, but the validation is not working. I am new to JQ and Ajax so any help would be apprecated.

Note:required validation message working fine but when fill mobile number already exist
     and click submit Nothing happening
Thanks.

MY FORM:

```
<form  name="form" id="form" action="check_phone.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile"/></br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

MY SCRIPT:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
    mobile: {
    required: true,
    remote: {
    url: "check_phone.jsp",
    async:false,
    type: "post",
    data: {
      mobile: function() { return $("#mobile").val() }
     }
    }
   }
  },
    messages:{
     mobile:{remote:"alredy exist",required:"Require Field"}
       }
       });
       });
```

MY JSP PAGE :

```
               <%

           Connection con;
            Statement stm = null;
            ResultSet rs;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/DB_NAME","root","root");
        String mobile =request.getParameter("mobile");
        stm=con.createStatement();
         rs=stm.executeQuery("select * from student where mobile = '"+mobile+"'");
        if(rs.next()) {
          out.print("false");    //already exist  

           } else
      {
      out.print("true");   // not exist 
     }
                     }catch(SQLException e){
                         out.print(e);

                     }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                         out.print(e); 
                     }

                   %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer to my question, but I follow these documentation, as I mentioned before I am a beginner
[http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method]

Comment: Instead of having the validation inside `$(document).ready(function(){` put it in a named function and have the form's `onSubmit` method call that function.